# Hibernate one-to-one and one-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I currently have a one-to-many relation between 2 table: I have:

```
Table A (id, ...)
Table B (tableAId, ...) (has no id of it's own).
```

In the mapping this is done using <list>.

The issue I am having, is that I have to add another one to one relationship from A to B. Something like this:

```
class A {
    public B b; // new part
    public List<B> bs; // already existing part.
}
```

I have a boolean column in the table by which I should differentiate between the one-to-one and one-to-many. I'm not sure how to write the hibernate mapping for these tables. Could any of you help me out with this?

Comment: Perhaps, you should re-consider your architecture. I'm not sure Hibernate may (or should) handle it.

Comment: I would change the structure of this table, but the task I have requires me to adapt this old table :(.

Comment: Well, you may easily remap a new table from the old one using good old SQL (either via JDBC or via DB administration tool)

Comment: As I see, you'd only have to map both relationships (One-to-Many and Many-To-One) and deal with the boolean inside your application. Wouldn't that  work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using 'mappedBy', have you tried that?

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association